# Jasypt: Failed to bind properties under 'spring.datasource.password' to java.lang.String

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, spring-security, passwords

I am using Jasypt in my Spring Boot app and encrypted passwords in app properties and docker-compose using proper annotation:

***application.properties.yml:***

```
datasource:
  driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
  url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/employee_db
  username: postgres
  password: ENC(fpEVpMwMbl4hbcoCKuhrpi...)


# jasypt
jasypt:
  encryptor:
    algorithm: PBEWithMD5AndDES
    iv-generator-classname: org.jasypt.iv.NoIvGenerator
```

***docker-compose.yml:***

```
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:14.6-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: employee_db
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ENC(fpEVpMwMbl4hbcoCKuhrpi...)
```

After creating Docker image for database (db container), I add the VM options to IntelliJ and start the app. But I got the following error and cannot find a solution for that:

> Description: Failed to bind properties under 'spring.datasource.password' to java.lang.String:

> Reason: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'spring.datasource.password' to java.lang.String

> Action: Update your application's configuration

Any idea to solve the problem?

Here is the full log:

```
C:\Users\simpson\.jdks\corretto-17.0.5\bin\java.exe -Djasypt.encryptor.password=abnamro -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.jmx.enabled=true -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=53749:
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "D:\employee-api\target\classes;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\2.7.5\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.7.5.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\2.7.5\spring-boot-starter-aop-2.7.5.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.3.23\spring-aop-5.3.23.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.9.7\aspectjweaver-1.9.7.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\2.7.5\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.7.5.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\com\zaxxer\HikariCP\4.0.3\HikariCP-4.0.3.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\5.3.23\spring-jdbc-5.3.23.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\jakarta\transaction\jakarta.transaction-api\1.3.3\jakarta.transaction-api-1.3.3.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\jakarta\persistence\jakarta.persistence-api\2.2.3\jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.6.12.Final\hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.4.3.Final\jboss-logging-3.4.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.12.18\byte-buddy-1.12.18.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.4.2.Final\jandex-2.4.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.1.2.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\2.3.7\jaxb-runtime-2.3.7.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\txw2\2.3.7\txw2-2.3.7.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\com\sun\istack\istack-commons-runtime\3.0.12\istack-commons-runtime-3.0.12.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\com\sun\activation\jakarta.activation\1.2.2\jakarta.activation-1.2.2.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\2.7.5\spring-data-jpa-2.7.5.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\2.7.5\spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\5.3.23\spring-orm-5.3.23.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.3.23\spring-context-5.3.23.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\5.3.23\spring-tx-5.3.23.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.3.23\spring-beans-5.3.23.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\5.3.23\spring-aspects-5.3.23.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.7.5\spring-boot-starter-web-2.7.5.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.7.5\spring-boot-starter-2.7.5.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.7.5\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.7.5.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.11\logback-classic-1.2.11.jar;C:\Users\simpsson\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.11\logback-core-1.2.11.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.17.2\log4j-to-slf4j-2.17.2.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.17.2\log4j-api-2.17.2.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.36\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.36.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\1.3.5\jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.30\snakeyaml-1.30.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.7.5\spring-boot-starter-json-2.7.5.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.13.4.2\jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.13.4\jackson-annotations-2.13.4.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.13.4\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.13.4.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.13.4\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.13.4.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.13.4\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.13.4.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\2.7.5\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.7.5.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\9.0.68\tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\9.0.68\tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.68.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.3.23\spring-web-5.3.23.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\5.3.23\spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.3.23\spring-expression-5.3.23.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-validation\3.0.0\spring-boot-starter-validation-3.0.0.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\9.0.68\tomcat-embed-el-9.0.68.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\validator\hibernate-validator\6.2.5.Final\hibernate-validator-6.2.5.Final.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\jakarta\validation\jakarta.validation-api\2.0.2\jakarta.validation-api-2.0.2.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-devtools\2.7.5\spring-boot-devtools-2.7.5.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.7.5\spring-boot-2.7.5.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.7.5\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.5.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\org\projectlombok\lombok\1.18.24\lombok-1.18.24.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\io\springfox\springfox-boot-starter\3.0.0\springfox-boot-starter-3.0.0.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\io\springfox\springfox-oas\3.0.0\springfox-oas-3.0.0.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\io\swagger\core\v3\swagger-annotations\2.1.2\swagger-annotations-2.1.2.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\io\swagger\core\v3\swagger-models\2.1.2\swagger-models-2.1.2.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\io\springfox\springfox-spi\3.0.0\springfox-spi-3.0.0.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\io\springfox\springfox-schema\3.0.0\springfox-schema-3.0.0.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\io\springfox\springfox-core\3.0.0\springfox-core-3.0.0.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\io\springfox\springfox-spring-web\3.0.0\springfox-spring-web-3.0.0.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\io\github\classgraph\classgraph\4.8.83\classgraph-4.8.83.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\io\springfox\springfox-spring-webmvc\3.0.0\springfox-spring-webmvc-3.0.0.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\io\springfox\springfox-spring-webflux\3.0.0\springfox-spring-webflux-3.0.0.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\io\springfox\springfox-swagger-common\3.0.0\springfox-swagger-common-3.0.0.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\org\mapstruct\mapstruct\1.3.1.Final\mapstruct-1.3.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\io\springfox\springfox-data-rest\3.0.0\springfox-data-rest-3.0.0.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\io\springfox\springfox-bean-validators\3.0.0\springfox-bean-validators-3.0.0.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\io\springfox\springfox-swagger2\3.0.0\springfox-swagger2-3.0.0.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\io\swagger\swagger-annotations\1.5.20\swagger-annotations-1.5.20.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\io\swagger\swagger-models\1.5.20\swagger-models-1.5.20.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\io\springfox\springfox-swagger-ui\3.0.0\springfox-swagger-ui-3.0.0.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.5.1\classmate-1.5.1.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.36\slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\org\springframework\plugin\spring-plugin-core\2.0.0.RELEASE\spring-plugin-core-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\org\springframework\plugin\spring-plugin-metadata\2.0.0.RELEASE\spring-plugin-metadata-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-text\1.10.0\commons-text-1.10.0.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.12.0\commons-lang3-3.12.0.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\com\github\ulisesbocchio\jasypt-spring-boot-starter\3.0.3\jasypt-spring-boot-starter-3.0.3.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\com\github\ulisesbocchio\jasypt-spring-boot\3.0.3\jasypt-spring-boot-3.0.3.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\org\jasypt\jasypt\1.9.3\jasypt-1.9.3.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\org\flywaydb\flyway-core\9.8.3\flyway-core-9.8.3.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\dataformat\jackson-dataformat-toml\2.13.4\jackson-dataformat-toml-2.13.4.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.13.4\jackson-core-2.13.4.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\org\postgresql\postgresql\42.5.1\postgresql-42.5.1.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\org\checkerframework\checker-qual\3.5.0\checker-qual-3.5.0.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\jakarta\xml\bind\jakarta.xml.bind-api\2.3.3\jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\jakarta\activation\jakarta.activation-api\1.2.2\jakarta.activation-api-1.2.2.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.3.23\spring-core-5.3.23.jar;C:\Users\simpson\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.3.23\spring-jcl-5.3.23.jar" com.demo.EmployeeApiApplication
19:35:35.056 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader - Created RestartClassLoader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@4a79e7d6
2022-12-10 19:35:35,468 INFO  com.demo.EmployeeApiApplication : Starting EmployeeApiApplication using Java 17.0.5 on DESKTOP-1J43AAP with PID 27224 (D:\Archive\_HR\Applications\Interview\ABN Amro\assignment\solution\employee-api\target\classes started by simpson in D:\Archive\_HR\Applications\Interview\ABN Amro\assignment\solution\employee-api)
2022-12-10 19:35:35,468 DEBUG com.demo.EmployeeApiApplication : Running with Spring Boot v2.7.5, Spring v5.3.23
2022-12-10 19:35:35,469 INFO  com.demo.EmployeeApiApplication : The following 1 profile is active: "production"
2022-12-10 19:35:36,533 INFO  com.ulisesbocchio.jasyptspringboot.configuration.EnableEncryptablePropertiesBeanFactoryPostProcessor : Post-processing PropertySource instances
2022-12-10 19:35:36,549 INFO  com.ulisesbocchio.jasyptspringboot.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter : Converting PropertySource configurationProperties [org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertySource] to AOP Proxy
2022-12-10 19:35:36,550 INFO  com.ulisesbocchio.jasyptspringboot.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter : Converting PropertySource servletConfigInitParams [org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource$StubPropertySource] to EncryptablePropertySourceWrapper
2022-12-10 19:35:36,550 INFO  com.ulisesbocchio.jasyptspringboot.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter : Converting PropertySource servletContextInitParams [org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource$StubPropertySource] to EncryptablePropertySourceWrapper
2022-12-10 19:35:36,551 INFO  com.ulisesbocchio.jasyptspringboot.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter : Converting PropertySource systemProperties [org.springframework.core.env.PropertiesPropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper
2022-12-10 19:35:36,551 INFO  com.ulisesbocchio.jasyptspringboot.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter : Converting PropertySource systemEnvironment [org.springframework.boot.env.SystemEnvironmentPropertySourceEnvironmentPostProcessor$OriginAwareSystemEnvironmentPropertySource] to EncryptableSystemEnvironmentPropertySourceWrapper
2022-12-10 19:35:36,551 INFO  com.ulisesbocchio.jasyptspringboot.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter : Converting PropertySource random [org.springframework.boot.env.RandomValuePropertySource] to EncryptablePropertySourceWrapper
2022-12-10 19:35:36,551 INFO  com.ulisesbocchio.jasyptspringboot.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter : Converting PropertySource Config resource 'class path resource [application.yml]' via location 'optional:classpath:/' [org.springframework.boot.env.OriginTrackedMapPropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper
2022-12-10 19:35:36,551 INFO  com.ulisesbocchio.jasyptspringboot.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter : Converting PropertySource devtools [org.springframework.core.env.MapPropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper
2022-12-10 19:35:36,579 INFO  com.ulisesbocchio.jasyptspringboot.filter.DefaultLazyPropertyFilter : Property Filter custom Bean not found with name 'encryptablePropertyFilter'. Initializing Default Property Filter
2022-12-10 19:35:36,703 INFO  com.ulisesbocchio.jasyptspringboot.resolver.DefaultLazyPropertyResolver : Property Resolver custom Bean not found with name 'encryptablePropertyResolver'. Initializing Default Property Resolver
2022-12-10 19:35:36,704 INFO  com.ulisesbocchio.jasyptspringboot.detector.DefaultLazyPropertyDetector : Property Detector custom Bean not found with name 'encryptablePropertyDetector'. Initializing Default Property Detector
2022-12-10 19:35:36,923 INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-12-10 19:35:36,923 INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.68]
2022-12-10 19:35:36,979 INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-12-10 19:35:37,053 INFO  com.ulisesbocchio.jasyptspringboot.encryptor.DefaultLazyEncryptor : Found Custom Encryptor Bean org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.PooledPBEStringEncryptor@220275ac with name: jasyptStringEncryptor
2022-12-10 19:35:37,082 INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-12-10 19:35:37,114 ERROR org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to bind properties under 'spring.datasource.password' to java.lang.String:

    Reason: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'spring.datasource.password' to java.lang.String

Action:

Update your application's configuration


Process finished with exit code 0
```

I run the project using IntelliJ IDEA by selecting `Run` -> `Edit Configurations` and in the `Build and run` section, add the following value to the VM options field and run the application: `-Djasypt.encryptor.password=my-secret`

Comment: Were you ever able to find an answer to this?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem, hope you can follow the following ideas to troubleshoot the problem.

1. First, check whether your encryption and decryption parameters are the same.
   Since jasypt 3.0, the default configuration has changed.
   Here are the relevant parameters

   ```
    jasypt:
     encryptor:
       password: your_pwd
       iv-generator-classname: org.jasypt.iv.RandomIvGenerator
       algorithm: PBEWITHHMACSHA512ANDAES_256
   ```

   If your cipher was generated before the maven dependency was upgraded, try rolling back the jasypt version or use the following parameters:

   ```
   jasypt:
     encryptor:
       password: your_pwd
       iv-generator-classname: org.jasypt.iv.NoIvGenerator
       algorithm: PBEWithMD5AndDES
   ```
2. If changing the above parameters does not work, consider whether you are using the advanced encryption algorithm provided by jasypt.

   The default algorithm used in jsaypt 3.0 and above is not supported in jdk1.8, you can add [JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jce-all-downloads.html) or upgrade JDK version to 1.9+ to use advanced encryption algorithms.

   **Code to test which algorithms are not supported**

   ```
       @GetMapping("/jasypt")
       public String testJasypt() {
           Set<String> supported = new HashSet<>();
           Set<String> unsupported = new HashSet<>();
           for (Object algorithms : AlgorithmRegistry.getAllPBEAlgorithms()) {
               String algo = (String) algorithms;
               try {
                   StandardPBEStringEncryptor encryptor = new StandardPBEStringEncryptor();
                   encryptor.setAlgorithm(algo);
                   encryptor.setPassword("kingkong"); 
                   encryptor.setIvGenerator(new RandomIvGenerator());
                   String encrypted = encryptor.encrypt("foo");
                   String decrypted = encryptor.decrypt(encrypted);
                   AssertUtil.isTrue(StringUtils.equals(decrypted,"foo"),"unSupport");
                   supported.add(algo);
               } catch (EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException e) {
                   unsupported.add(algo);
               }
           }

           return supported + "\n\n" + unsupported;

       }
   ```

**For my test, these algorithms are not supported under jdk8**

- PBEWITHHMACSHA224ANDAES_256
- PBEWITHHMACSHA512ANDAES_256
- PBEWITHHMACSHA256ANDAES_256
- PBEWITHHMACSHA384ANDAES_256
- PBEWITHHMACSHA1ANDAES_256
- PBEWITHMD5ANDTRIPLEDES

Answer (score 0):

Try to downgrade to 2.0.0 version of jasypt-spring-boot-starter

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Configuration
public class JasyptEncryptorConfiguratuin {
    @Bean("jasyptStringEncryptor")
    public StringEncryptor stringEncryptor() {
        PooledPBEStringEncryptor encryptor = new PooledPBEStringEncryptor();
        SimpleStringPBEConfig config = new SimpleStringPBEConfig();
        config.setPassword("password");
        config.setAlgorithm("PBEWITHHMACSHA512ANDAES_256");
        config.setKeyObtentionIterations("1000");
        config.setPoolSize("1");
        config.setProviderName("SunJCE");
         
        
        config.setSaltGeneratorClassName("org.jasypt.salt.RandomSaltGenerator");
        config.setIvGeneratorClassName("org.jasypt.iv.RandomIvGenerator");
        config.setStringOutputType("base64");
        encryptor.setConfig(config);
        return encryptor;
    }
}
```

Comment: try with this and add @SpringBootApplication with the main class and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error when using `ENC(enc_password)` in properties/yaml file, where
`enc_password`  was generated using
`mvn jasypt:encrypt-value -Djasypt.encryptor.password=password -Djasypt.plugin.value=Master_key`

I got rid of the errors by using `DEC(password)` in properties/yaml file then running

```
mvn jasypt:encrypt -Djasypt.encryptor.password=Master_Key -Djasypt.plugin.path="file:src/main/resources/application.properties"
```

to replace `DEC(password)` with `ENC(enc_password)`

Answer (score 0):

I currently face the same issue but get rid of it by adding the following:

`jasypt.encryptor.iv-generator-classname=org.jasypt.iv.NoIvGenerator`

on the property file.
Hope this would help you.

Answer (score -1):

The primary purpose of naming a bean like this is for clarity and organization within your application's configuration. It helps you distinguish one bean from another and makes it easier to reference this specific bean when you need to inject it into other parts of your application. For example, you may need to inject the StringEncryptor bean into services or other components that require encryption or decryption.

```yaml
# application.yml
jasypt:
  encryptor:
    bean: jasyptStringEncryptor
    password: your_password
```

```java
@Configuration
public class JasyptConfig {
    @Value("${jasypt.encryptor.password}")
    private String secretKey;
    
    @Bean("jasyptStringEncryptor")
    public StringEncryptor encryptor() {
        // your configuration setup
        return stringEncryptor();
    }
}
```

In this configuration, you're specifying that you want to use the "jasyptStringEncryptor" bean as the encryptor for your application. By naming the bean, you can reference it explicitly in your configuration, making it clear which bean should be used for encryption.